# PHP not able to grab url variable after loading content through ajax

Tags: php, jquery

so here is my scenario.  I have a page, lets use "http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/listen.php?u=161"  On the page load it loads a file, ajaxlinklisten.php  into a div on my listen.php page through ajax and jquery.  Inside of my ajaxlinklisten.php page I have the following code:

```
if (isset($_GET['u']));
{
$music3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
```

However, for some reason ajaxlinklisten is unable to get the variable, u, which in this case is equal to 161.  This variable is important because I use it to process the rest of the page.  I don't know if this is caused because I am using jquery to load the page, but I need to find a work-around.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you load the page via AJAX it is not getting the variable, it is treated separately from your original load. Pass it data with:

`data: 'u=' + <?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>,`

In the ajax part of your page.

**Edit**

I imagine your ajax is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   success: function(data){
      *do stuff
   }
});
```

Add more

```
$.ajax({
   data: 'u=' + <?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>,
   type: GET,
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   success: function(data){
      *do stuff
   }
});
```

It depends how you implemented the script but that should get you where you need to go.

Comment: How do I then take this ajax code and get it with the PHP?  DO I use the same function that I am currently using?

Comment: @DavidNguyen: You incorrectly include GET parameter within your JavaScript. Please fix your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could not use PHP and use an javascript URL parser, here is a quick one i came up with (i'm sure you could make a MUCH better implementation with this using regex).

if your URL is "www.example.com?foo=bar&u=160, this function will return an object {foo:"bar", u:"160"}.

```
function parseUrl()
{
    str = String(window.location);

    var vars = new Array();
    var cont = true;
    var name;
    var val;

    if (str.indexOf("?") > -1)
    {
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf("?") + 1);

        if (str.indexOf("#") > -1)
        {
            str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("#"));
        }

        do
        {
            name = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("="));

            if (name !== "")
            {
                if (str.indexOf("&") > -1)
                {
                    val = str.substr(str.indexOf("=") + 1, str.indexOf("&") - str.indexOf("=") - 1);
                    str = str.substr(str.indexOf("&") + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    val = str.substr(str.indexOf("=") + 1);
                    cont = false;
                }

                vars[name] = val.replace(/[+]/g, " ");
            }
            else
            {
                cont = false;
            }

        } while (cont);
    }

    return vars;
}
```

Comment: Do not mess with global namespace.